# gwt celltable paging

Tags: gwt

I have celltable and a simplepager. I am making async calls to the server to return data as a list.

```
AsyncDataProvider<Entry> provider = new AsyncDataProvider<Entry>() {
            @Override
            protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<Entry> display) {
                final int start = display.getVisibleRange().getStart();
                int length = display.getVisibleRange().getLength();

                AsyncCallback<List<Entry>> callback = new AsyncCallback<List<Entry>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                        Window.alert(caught.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<Entry> result) {                         
                        updateRowData(start, result);
                    }
                };

                // The remote service that should be implemented
                rpcService.fetchEntries(start, length, callback);
            }
        };
```

On the server side ...

```
public List<Entry> fetchEntries(int start, int length) {
        if (start > ENTRIES.size())
            return new ArrayList<Entry>();

        int end = start + length > ENTRIES.size() ? ENTRIES.size() : start
                + length;
        ArrayList<Entry> sublist = new ArrayList<Entry>(
                (List<Entry>) ENTRIES.subList(start, end));
        return sublist;
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know the size of the dataset returned by the aync call. So I cannot set the updateRowCount. So now the next button is always active even though the dataset has only 24 fields. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

How about modifying your RPC service to return a flag as well:

```
class FetchEntriesResult{
  private int totalNumberOfEntries;
  private List<Entry> entries;
  //getters,setters, constructor etc...
}
```

And your service method becomes something like:

```
public FetchEntriesResult fetchEntries(int start, int length) {

       if (start > ENTRIES.size())
            return new ArrayList<Entry>();

        int end = start + length > ENTRIES.size() ? ENTRIES.size() : start
                + length;
        ArrayList<Entry> sublist = new ArrayList<Entry>(
                (List<Entry>) ENTRIES.subList(start, end));
        return new FetchEntriesResult(sublist,ENTRIES.size());
}
```

Now you can use the `FetchEntriesResult.getTotalNumberOfEntries()` on the client.